# sql to find number of attendees (joined) of an event

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to find number of attendees who have actually joined the sessions of the event. I've 5 tables.

```
event -> day -> session

attendee

session_attendee
```

**Schema**

```
+------------------------------+
|           attendee           |
+------------------------------+
| id  username    password     |
| 1   user1       test         |
| 2   user2       test         |
| ------                       |
| event                        |
| id  name                     |
| 1   event 1                  |
| 2   event 2                  |
| -----                        |
| day                          |
| id  date            event_id |
| 1   '2015-06-01'    1        |
| 2   '2015-06-02'    1        |
| 3   '2015-07-01'    2        |
| 4   '2015-07-02'    2        |
| ------                       |
| session                      |
| id  name        day_id       |
| 1   session a   1            |
| 2   session b   1            |
| 3   session c   2            |
| 4   session d   2            |
| ------                       |
| session_attendee             |
| id  session_id  attendee_id  |
| 1   1           1            |
| 2   2           1            |
| 3   1           2            |
| 4   2           2            |
+------------------------------+
```

**Expectation**

```
+-----------------------------+
|  id  name        attendees  |
+-----------------------------+
| 1   'event 1'   2           |
| 2   'event 2'   0/null etc. |
+-----------------------------+
```

**Subquery**

SQL query I've tried using Joins but it's returning more than one record (i.e. I can't use it as a subquery)

```
SELECT count(*) FROM event
INNER JOIN day ON event.id = day.event_id 
INNER JOIN session ON day.id = session.day_id
INNER JOIN session_attendee ON session.id = session_attendee.session_id
WHERE event.id = 1
GROUP BY attendee_id
```

**Parent Query**

with above subquery substituted

```
SELECT id, name,  
(SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM day WHERE day.event_id = event.id) AS days,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM event
INNER JOIN day ON event.id = day.event_id 
INNER JOIN session ON day.id = session.day_id
INNER JOIN session_attendee ON session.id = session_attendee.session_id
GROUP BY session_attendee.attendee_id) AS attendees
FROM event;
```

**SQL Fiddle**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/72ffc

---

**More Work:**

```
SELECT event.id, event.name,
(SELECT count(*) FROM event e INNER JOIN day AS d ON e.id = d.event_id WHERE e.id = event.id) AS total_days,
day.date, session.name, session_attendee.attendee_id
FROM event
LEFT JOIN day ON event.id = day.event_id
LEFT JOIN session ON day.id = session.day_id
LEFT JOIN session_attendee ON session.id = session_attendee.session_id
ORDER BY event.id;
```

-- COUNT(distinct attendee_id) AS attendees

As soon as I enter `COUNT(distinct attendee_id)`, my result set gets reduced to one row, i.e. I don't get to see records for other events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first query looks basically right with one exception:  if you want information for an event, you should aggregate by the event id, not the attendee id:

```
SELECT e.id, e.name, count(*)
FROM event e INNER JOIN
     day d
     ON e.id = d.event_id INNER JOIN
     session s
     ON d.id = s.day_id INNER JOIN
     session_attendee sa
     ON s.id = sa.session_id
GROUP BY e.id;
```

Of course, if you want information for only one event, you can replace the `GROUP BY` with:

```
WHERE e.id = 1
```

EDIT:

You want a `LEFT JOIN` to keep all the events:

```
SELECT e.id, e.name, count(distinct sa.attendee_id)
FROM event e LEFT JOIN
     day d
     ON e.id = d.event_id LEFT JOIN
     session s
     ON d.id = s.day_id LEFT JOIN
     session_attendee sa
     ON s.id = sa.session_id
GROUP BY e.id;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I've copied but the query was returning me count 4 instead of 2, ` 1   'event 1'   4`, and moreover, I'm trying to have it substituted with parent query as well so i get the name of the event, and it's total number of attendees, sql fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/72ffc/5

Comment: Perhaps you want `count(distinct attendee_id)` rather than `count(*)`.

Comment: great, I've got the two now, but my expectation is to have the all the events returned with their number of attendees, i.e. also event 2 with 0 attendees, updated sql -> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/72ffc/7

Comment: this `COUNT(distinct attendee_id)` function knows which attendee_id is in the question, so you could basically apply count on any column

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT event.id, name,
   (SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM day WHERE day.event_id = event.id) AS days,
   b.number_of_attendee
   FROM event
   left join (
           SELECT a.id, count(*) as number_of_attendee from
           (
            SELECT event.id, attendee_id FROM event
            INNER JOIN day ON event.id = day.event_id 
            INNER JOIN session ON day.id = session.day_id
            INNER JOIN session_attendee ON session.id = session_attendee.session_id
            group by event.id, attendee_id
           ) as a
           group by a.id) as b

   on b.id = event.id
```

which has the result like

```
id  name    days    number_of_attendee
1   Event 1     2   2
2   Event 2     2   (null)
```