# sql query to find all the sessions of the events with number of attendees

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get all the sessions of an event and then count of all the attendees who have subscribed to that event (session_attendee table).

**My Schema**

5 Tables

*Event -> day -> session*

*attendee*

*session_attendee*

```
+------------------------------+
|           attendee           |
+------------------------------+
| id  username    password     |
| 1   user1       test         |
| 2   user2       test         |
| ------                       |
| event                        |
| id  name                     |
| 1   event 1                  |
| 2   event 2                  |
| 3   event 3                  |
| -----                        |
| day                          |
| id  date            event_id |
| 1   '2015-06-01'    1        |
| 2   '2015-06-02'    1        |
| 3   '2015-07-01'    2        |
| 4   '2015-07-02'    2        |
| ------                       |
| session                      |
| id  name        day_id       |
| 1   session a   1            |
| 2   session b   1            |
| 3   session c   2            |
| 4   session d   2            |
| ------                       |
| session_attendee             |
| id  session_id  attendee_id  |
| 1   1           1            |
| 2   2           1            |
| 3   1           2            |
| 4   2           2            |
+------------------------------+
```

**My Expectation**

```
+--------------+-----------+
| Session Name | Attendees |
+--------------+-----------+
| session a    |         2 |
| session b    |         2 |
| session c    |         0 |
| session d    |         0 |
+--------------+-----------+
```

**My Attempt** (it might have some extra columns)

```
SELECT day.event_id, session.id, session.name,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM day WHERE day.event_id = event.id) AS days,
(SELECT COUNT(distinct attendee_id)) AS attendees
FROM event
LEFT JOIN day ON event.id = day.event_id
LEFT JOIN session ON day.id = session.day_id
LEFT JOIN session_attendee ON session.id = session_attendee.session_id
WHERE day.event_id = 1
ORDER BY day.date, session.start;
```

**SQL Fiddle**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/72ffc

Edit

Guys, please check this out, it works, any comments please.

```
SELECT event.id, day.date, session.name, session.day_id, session_attendee.id, session_attendee.session_id, session_attendee.attendee_id,
COUNT(distinct attendee_id) AS attendees,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM day WHERE day.event_id = 1) AS days
FROM session
RIGHT JOIN session_attendee ON session.id = session_attendee.session_id 
RIGHT JOIN day ON session.day_id = day.id
RIGHT JOIN event ON day.event_id = event.id
WHERE event_id = 1
GROUP BY session.name
ORDER BY day.date;
```

Comment: Please identify your Primary and Foreign keys.

Comment: I'm wondering how can identify in a better way, basically any id's is PK, while `attendee_id` means it's a foreign key to `attendee` table, basically the `tablename_id` identifies it as foreign key to the tablename

Comment: You posted the same question yesterday (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30293893/sql-to-find-number-of-attendees-joined-of-an-event) and got a correct answer already

Comment: @dnoeth this is different, it's all of the sessions that might have joined or not, difference is in the details, and as you can see queries are different and still trying to work it out

Answer (score 0):

select s.name, count(a.id) from session s left join session_attendee sa on s.id=sa.session_id left join attendee a on a.id = sa.attendee_id group by s.name

Comment: how can we filter by sessions belonging to specific event, I've to filter using `event_id = 1` something

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT s.name
     , COUNT(DISTINCT sa.attendee_id) 
  FROM session s
  LEFT 
  JOIN session_attendee sa
    ON sa.session_id = s.id 
  LEFT 
  JOIN day d
    ON d.id = s.day_id
   AND d.event_id = 1
 GROUP 
    BY s.name
```

Comment: I'm wondering why you're joining to `day` since you're not doing anything with it. Perhaps the plan was to keep going and show the event name rather than the session name? I'd group on `session.id` rather than `session.name` just to be safe.

Comment: @MarcusAdams anything is good, I've actually more fields, my question was a narrow down version

Comment: @strawberry the query works, but there's a little bit glitch, if you substitute `d.even_id = 2` or 3 or 4, the result stays the same, i.e. all the sessions are pulled from all the events.

Answer (score 0):

The query is almost the same as the [previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30293893/sql-to-find-number-of-attendees-joined-of-an-event), you just have to change the join-order. Now then `session` table is the left-most table:

```
SELECT s.name, count(distinct sa.attendee_id)
FROM session s 
LEFT JOIN day d
  ON d.id = s.day_id 
LEFT JOIN event e 
  ON e.id = d.event_id 
LEFT JOIN session_attendee sa
     ON s.id = sa.session_id
GROUP BY s.name;
```

See [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/72ffc/43)

Edit: [It's even simpler](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/72ffc/46), no need to join to `event` and `day` and no distinct:

```
SELECT s.name, count(sa.attendee_id)
FROM session s 
LEFT JOIN session_attendee sa
     ON s.id = sa.session_id
GROUP BY s.name;
```

Comment: Yes I got my head around it, I have to start basically from the session table, It's actually very complex query, I tried to narrow down in here, my edit has the one I'm going to use, I'll try to incroporate best from your answer. Also it's not simpler, we need to filter by event_id (passed parameter) thats where I'm stuck, and I think that's why I need all this joins to reach to event table.

Comment: Plesae check out my answer, I've a filter in the query for event_id, hopefully it will help you to understand what I was trying to look for, but never the less, it's all bits and pieces that I collected from community to make something I needed

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for all the bits and pieces that I could collect together to work out a query, as you can see the query is complex and I had to go through back and forth with the community but thanks for your patience. Please bear with me if I have similar hiccup down the road, it's just that a slight difference in requirements makes me ask another question.

```
SELECT session.id, session.name, session.start, session.end, session.room,
DATE_FORMAT(day.date, '%m/%d/%Y') AS date, day.name,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM day WHERE day.event_id = 1) AS days,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM session_attendee WHERE session_attendee.session_id = session.id) AS attendees
FROM event
LEFT JOIN day ON event.id = day.event_id
LEFT JOIN session ON day.id = session.day_id
LEFT JOIN session_attendee ON session.id = session_attendee.session_id
WHERE event.id = 1
ORDER BY day.date, session.start;
```